# Facebook integration with custom button

Tags: android

I am creating an app in which I want to integrate `facebook sdk`. I want to login user with `facebook`, but it's creating problem.

It's working only one time. If I install the app and login with `facebook` it's working but when I uninstall my app and try to install and login again with `facebook` it's not working. It is not asking for `access permission` and doing nothing.

I want to ask one more question, I want to make *custom facebook login button* and after successfully login go to next `Activity`.

Here what I have already done. I don't know where is mistake?

Here is my main xml:

```
           <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnFblogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:src="@drawable/fb_signin" />

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
```

Here is my fragment :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
   btnFbLog = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFblogin);
   btnFbLog.setOnClickListener(this);
       return view;}

  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnFblogin:
            mSignInClicked = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on facebook login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            fbloginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    //updateFacebookButtonUI();
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    loginSocial(profile.getId(), Const.SOCIAL_FACEBOOK);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                }
            });

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);



 private void loginSocial(String id, String loginType) {
    if (!AndyUtils.isNetworkAvailable(activity)) {
        AndyUtils.showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet),
                activity);
        return;
    }
    AndyUtils.showCustomProgressDialog(activity,
            getResources().getString(R.string.text_signin), false, null);
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(Const.URL, Const.ServiceType.LOGIN);
    map.put(Const.Params.SOCIAL_UNIQUE_ID, id);
    map.put(Const.Params.DEVICE_TYPE, Const.DEVICE_TYPE_ANDROID);
    map.put(Const.Params.DEVICE_TOKEN,
            new PreferenceHelper(activity).getDeviceToken());
    map.put(Const.Params.LOGIN_BY, loginType);
    new HttpRequester(activity, map, Const.ServiceCode.LOGIN, this);

}
```

Comment: Do you have facebook app installed on phone? Can u reproduce you issue, when its not installed?

Comment: yes,facebook is installed on my device

Comment: Have you look into `onError(..)`?

Comment: @user7108398 Well, Facebook app saves your session and skips login/permission check, you should just proceed to do whatever you need in `onSuccess`. If you uninstall Facebook app, you will be prompted to enter login/pass everytime you logout

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create your custom facebook login button via `com.facebook.login.LoginManager`. Facebook button is only wrapper for this class.

Sample:

```
private void loginWithFacebook() {
    if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null) {
        //logout
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    } else {
        //login
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityLogin.this, "onSuccess: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityLogin.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityLogin.this, "onError: " + error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: i have put this code in onclick on "btnFblogin" according to my code?

Comment: Yes, you can call it from anywhere. In your case you want call `loginWithFacebook()` in your `btnFbLogin.onClick()`. But you need to manage login/logout states of drawable/text by your own.